# How to fetch the status of profile flag?

Tags: users, flags

I have a profile flag called "keep my photos private" using which user can flag his content and can keep it private. I want to fetch the status of the flag by the specific user. I have tried php code but its not working.

```
global $user;
$user_uid=arg(1);
$flag=flag_get_flag('keep_photos_private');
print "Flag Name : ".$flag->title;
print "User : ".$user_uid;
if($flag->is_flagged($user_uid)) { 
  print "flagged";
}
else {
  print "not flagged";
}
```

Is my code wrong?

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you having any issues?

Comment: Yes, its not at all executing if() body.

Comment: ^indeed, just check that each variable is set like you'd expect, eg, if you are sitting at `user/123`, make sure $user_uid is actually set to `123`, that `flag_name` is set actually `$flag_name` or an appropriate value, etc. Also confirm that this is a `user` flag, eg, that it expects the flag id to be a user id.

Comment: @Jimajamma I have edited code in my question. Its setting correct values to the $flag and $user_uid. But printing else part even if the flag is flagged.

Comment: Gotcha, then you have to look to see if this flag is using the `user uid` as the flag id. I see you tagged this with profile2.  If this flag is on that entity instead of the user itself, then the flag id will/should be the id of the profile2 entity, not the user id....

Comment: @Jimajamma yes it takes profile id as a flag id. I ended up with taking $profile->pid as u suggested. Its working fine now. Thank u Jimajamma.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Profile2 a while ago and it was not a joy for me. I remember having to implement a hook_user_insert and creating the profile right there and there as the profile was only created after a user saved a new profile. So if you have a flag on it and flag it without saving the profile it might just go lost as the profile does not really exist yet.

Comment: as it is a form, and until you submit the form it will not update the database. And flag status also effects the database on form submission only.